# Find computers with a specific user in local admin group

Tags: powershell

I need to check if a specific domain user is a member of a local administrators group.

I prefer to use Powershell, but the problem is that we are not allowing WinRM so I can't use PSRemoting, so I can't run `Get-LocalGroupMember` or something.

Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Without PSRemoting you can't.

Comment: ok, so any other suggestions?

Comment: You could use a PowerShell script which writes the data you want onto a share for example and deploy it as startup script using a GPO.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to have a look on [PowerView](https://github.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit/blob/master/Recon/PowerView.ps1). `Get-NetLocalGroup` queries the information via WinNT provider or on demand via WinAPI.

Refer to [harmj0y's blog](https://www.harmj0y.net/blog/tag/powerview/) for more information.